# R Markdown - Column Names - Static/Dynamic

Tags: r, r-markdown, names

I'm doing a report related to Real Estate in R Markdown. Column names are Sales.Amount, Sales.Ratio and Assessed.Value. (Separator is a dot)

In the report, I'm sharing the data frames, and the name of the columns are Sales.Amount, Sales.Ratio and Assessed.Value.

[image]

Is there any way I can set the visualized names in columns as "Sales Amount", but keep the column names in the data frame as "Sale.Amount" in order to don't have to change the code?

Comment: Set the column name to “Sales Amount”? It does create the hassle that you will always need to quote that value, but it could be a temporary fix that you could later reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing a report using R Markdown, you can change the column label for the output by using the `kable()` function in the `knitr` package:

```
library(knitr)
kable(df, col.names = c("Assessed Value","Sale Amount","Sales Ratio"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it your very last step before displaying your df.

```
colnames(df)[3] <- "Assessed Value"
colnames(df)[4] <- "Sale Amount"
colnames(df)[5] <- "Sales Ratio"
```